# paypal issue with base currency INR

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

Is there any way in Magento where I can integrate Paypal with base currency INR?

I am using magento 1.9.1

PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605:

i tried these but facing same issue

https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2014/07/inr-currency-convert-issue-with-paypal.html

Comment: have you enabled INR currency  in Paypal end?

Comment: No i have not done that.How to do that ?

Comment: Please see https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Receive-money-in-INR-curreccy/m-p/201016#M3429

Answer (score 2):

Override **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php**

```
Change this array
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

To

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB','INR');
```

**Another trick :**

Override  **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php**

Then change this function

```
public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
  return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
    }
To
public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
     if($currencyCode == 'INR')
   {
   $currencyCode = 'USD';
   }
  return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
    }
```